# Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance when acalling axios.get again

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have this function that populates select component when web page opens:

```
async mounted() {
  const [darwinProjectResponse, thirdPartyResponse] = await Promise.all([
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/projects?placeholder=darwin"),
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/thirdparty")
  ]);
  this.projects = [{
    "projectType": "Github Projects",
    "grpValues": darwinProjectResponse.data.projects,
  },{
    "projectType": "Thirdparty Projects",
    "grpValues": thirdPartyResponse.data,
  }];
}
```

Now I have created a hyperlink in theh vue template that I want to be able to click and force relaod the select component.

```
 <div class="round-button">
        <div class="round-button-circle">
            <a @click="reloadSelect" href="#">
                <img src="images/leftarrow.png"  alt="Reload" title="Sync with Github" />
            </a>
        </div>
</div>
```

So I have defined a function in the script tag, `reloadSelect`

```
function reloadSelect(force="false") {
       const [darwinProjectResponse, thirdPartyResponse] = Promise.all([
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/projects?placeholder=darwin&rc=" + force),
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/thirdparty")
      ]);

    console.log("Data fetched again");

      this.projects = [{
        "projectType": "Github Projects",
        "grpValues": darwinProjectResponse.data.projects,
      },{
        "projectType": "Thirdparty Projects",
        "grpValues": thirdPartyResponse.data,
      }];
}
```

**Note:** that I have removed `await` as I do not have `async` with `reloadSelect` to avoid syntax error.

and modified async mounted to call  this function `reloadSelect` so that Select also conitnues to populated when page is loaded , but it gives TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.

so I discovered `console.log("Data fetched again");` never runs.  which I assume somehting wrong how I am attempting to pull again.

Answer (score 2):

`Promise.all` returns a singular promise, not an array, so you can't destructure it. `Promise.all` *resolves* to an array once each promise is resolved.

Why not just make `reloadSelect` async?

```
async function reloadSelect(force="false") {
  const [darwinProjectResponse, thirdPartyResponse] = await Promise.all([
```

Or if you can't make it async for whatever reason, then use `then`, `await` is only syntax sugar over promises and `then`:

```
function reloadSelect(force="false") {
  Promise.all([
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/projects?placeholder=darwin&rc=" + force),
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/thirdparty")
  ]).then(([darwinProjectResponse, thirdPartyResponse]) => {
    this.projects = [{
      "projectType": "Github Projects",
      "grpValues": darwinProjectResponse.data.projects,
    },{
      "projectType": "Thirdparty Projects",
      "grpValues": thirdPartyResponse.data,
    }];
  });
```

Comment: yea thats, fine but I wanted to call reloadSelect from `async` mounted as well.. else I have duplicate code block